# Angular & Alertify: Multiple confirms with $index id's

Tags: javascript, angularjs, alertify

I have multiple buttons being generated by `ng-repeat`.  I am trying to link each button to the`alertify.js` confirm function.  I thought the best approach would be to generate each button's ID dynamically with `$index`, and then access `$index` via the controller.  I would think that the at least one of the buttons would work if `$index` was actually getting passed, but none of them work. I'm not asking anyone to post miracle code.  All I want is to know if the approach I am using is plausible, and if not, what are the alternatives?

**Controller logic**

```
function JsonController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.activeOn = true;
    $scope.activeOff = false;

    $http.get('flat.json')
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.flats = res.data;
        });

    /**
     * ALERTIFY LOGIC
     */
    $scope.confirmButton = function(index) {

          $('confirm-' + index).click(function(){

               alertify.confirm("Are you sure?",
                    function(){
                         alertify.success('Yes');
                    },
                    function(){
                         alertify.error('No');
                    });
          });
    }
}
```

**HTML button**

```
<button id="confirm-{{$index}}" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="confirmButton($index)">Rebuild</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a # in your jquery selector.

Should be `$('#confirm-' + index)` to select by id.

Comment: I literally just caught that right as you answered.